# React-redux, value from store get reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm setting a new value in the store by this action triggered with a click on a button:

```
onClick={() => { this.handleChange(values)
```

The function is:

```
handleChange = (values) => {
    const { setComponentSelected } = this.props;
    //some code 
    setComponentSelected(values);
    //some code 
}
```

With that, I can see in the Redux Dev Tools that my state is changed:

[image]

and in the dom I can see this changes ok.

But, another component is re-rendering this component where I have the problem. In this componente, I'm rendering like this way:

```
render() {

    const {  getComponentSelected } = this.props;
    console.log('getComponentSelected', getComponentSelected)
```

And this is how I use the store with redux:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  getComponentSelected: state.displayReportRecordReducers.setComponentSelected_data
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setComponentSelected: displayReportRecordActions.setComponentSelected,
}
```

I can see the changes from the `this.handleChange` at first, but everytime that the component gets mounted again, the values for this `console.log`is the old one, and not the same as I have in the store. There's no actions made with the remounting, the action that changes the store is only triggered with the `this.handleChange` so I don't know why is changes the value, and not showing what I have in the store.

Any idea?

EDIT:

My action is:

```
const setComponentSelected = (value: any) => {
  return async (dispatch: any) => {
    try {
      dispatch(success(value));
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log('error:', err);
    };
  }
  function success(value) {
    return { type: displayReportRecordConstants.SET_COMPONENT_SELECTED, payload: { value } };
  }
};
```

My reducer is:

```
case displayReportRecordConstants.SET_COMPONENT_SELECTED:
    return update(state, {
        setComponentSelected_data:           { $set: payload.value },
    });
```

EDIT 2: this scrennshots show the consistence between the store and the data that I render, at first click:
[image]

But if the components get re-rendered by another one, I lost the data in the console logs, whichs it's supossed to be get from the store. But the Redux dev tools show no changes!

[image]

Comment: You'll have to provide a [mcve] for us to be able to help.

Comment: Looks like there's unbalanced parentheses in your action which returns twice for some reason? Or we're not seeing the whole thing?

Comment: Sorry, fixed, needed a return. I'm trying to put only the more relevant code. Miss that.

Comment: can you try something and tell me about the result.. try not to user the destructure in the render method like `const {  getComponentSelected } = this.props;
` and user normal this.props.getComponentSelected and tell me if something changed.

Comment: @LouayAlosh same result in the console.log with both ways. I will add a link to a codesandbox here with the files that are relevant

Comment: the action method does not need to be async since it actually send an action to reducer only

Comment: @ducmai yes, I removed that, it wont affect anyway. This sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-sky-1lup1 has all the files, in order 1,2,3

Comment: It can be a bug with immutability-helper,  did you try replacing reducer's `case displayReportRecordConstants.SET_COMPONENT_SELECTED` with 
`return {
   ...state,
    setComponentSelected_data: payload.value
}`

Comment: @ShreyGupta I thought something like that. No, I haven't tested yet, but it's weird because I just copy pasted that way on the reducers, works ok with all of them. I will try though, thanks.

Comment: Happens the same... with `return { ...state,`